A calcultion of lifted character in local Zeta integral in Tate's thesis
I am reading Tate's thesis from Goldfeld and Hundley's book. I am currently stuck at one calculation in section 2.3 , it says if $v=p$ is ramified prime and $\omega$ is a lift of Dirichlet's character then
$\sum_{{j=1},(j,p)=1}^{p^r} e^{-\frac{2\pi ij}{p^l}}\omega(j)=0$ if $l<r$
I am not sure how it's zero. Any suggestion or comment is very helpful.

You do not indicate how $l$ and $r$ are related to $\omega$. Tha would make the question more self-contained.  Perhaps you can include an actual example as well.

You did not say that $p^r$ is the conductor of $\omega$, which is information in the book: $\omega$ is nontrivial on $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ (ramified) and is trivial on $1 + p^r\mathbf Z_p$ with $r \geq 1$ being minimal for that property (conductor is $p^r$). Since $\mathbf Z_p^\times/(1 + p^r\mathbf Z_p) \cong (\mathbf Z_p/p^r\mathbf Z_p)^\times$,
$\omega$ can be viewed as a Dirichlet character modulo $p^r$ that is not a lift of a Dirichlet character mod $p^{r-1}$, as otherwise $\omega$ on $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ would be trivial on $1 + p^{r-1}\mathbf Z_p$, contradicting the minimality of $r$. In more elementary terminology, $\omega$ is a primitive Dirichlet character mod $p^r$ with $r \geq 1$.
When $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character mod $m$ and $\zeta$ is an $m$th root of unity, their Gauss sum is
$$
G(\chi,\zeta) := \sum_{j \in \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times} \chi(j)\zeta^j 
$$
It is a fact that when $\chi$ is primitive mod $m$ and the $m$th root of unity $\zeta$ has order less than $m$, $G(\chi,\zeta) = 0$. This is what you need, with $m = p^r$, $\chi = \omega$, and $\zeta = e^{-2\pi i/p^l}$ since $l < r$.
That $G(\chi,\zeta) = 0$ is due to the sum of values of a nontrivial character over a finite abelian group being zero.
Let the order of $\zeta$ be $m'$, so $m' \mid m$ and $m' < m$.
Write $G(\chi,\zeta) = \sum_{j \bmod m} \chi(j)\zeta^j$ as a sum over
all $j$ that reduce to a common value $k \bmod m'$, so $\zeta^j$ is constant on such $j$:
$$
G(\chi,\zeta) = \sum_{k \in (\mathbf Z/m'\mathbf Z)^\times} \sum_{\substack{j \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \\ j \equiv k \bmod m'}}\chi(j)\zeta^j = 
\sum_{k \in (\mathbf Z/m'\mathbf Z)^\times} \zeta^{k} \sum_{\substack{j \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \\ j \equiv k \bmod m'}} \chi(j).
$$
We will show that the inner sums, for each $k$, are all $0$.
by expressing each inner sum as a sum over a nontrivial subgroup of $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$ by a change of variables.
Fix a unit $k \bmod m'$.
The natural reduction map $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \to (\mathbf Z/m'\mathbf Z)^\times$ is surjective, so we can
pick a unit $j_k \bmod m$ such that $j_k \equiv k \bmod m'$. (This is much simpler to see when $m$ is a prime power, which is all you need, so you can focus on such $m$ if you wish.)
The elements of $(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$ can be written as $j_k u$ with $u$ running over
$(\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times$, and we have $j_ku \equiv k \bmod m'$ if and only if $u \equiv 1 \bmod m'$, so
$$
 \sum_{\substack{j \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \\ j \equiv k \bmod m'}} \chi(j) = 
 \sum_{\substack{u \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \\ u \equiv 1 \bmod m'}} \chi(j_ku) = 
\chi(j_k) \sum_{\substack{u \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times \\ u \equiv 1 \bmod m'}} \chi(u).  
 $$
Since $\chi$ is primitive mod $m$ and $m'$ is a proper factor of $m$, $\chi$ is nontrivial on the subgroup $\{u \in (\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z)^\times : u \equiv 1 \bmod m'\}$, so the sum of $\chi$ over this subgroup is $0$.

What a shame what this site has become where answers like this get downvoted (and looking at the users voting to close it is pretty clear by whom)
